# Help!? While Control Structure Program!

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make "enter the account number" on the second loop. If I put "Enter the account number" in the "While" control structure. It would print twice in the first loop. So how can I fix this?

```
/* Make a program that will determine if a department store customer has exceeded the
credit limit on a charge account*/
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int aNum,Always;

    double balance,iTotal,cTotal,cLimit,NewBal;

    cout << "Enter account number: ";
        cin >> aNum;

     while ( aNum != -1 )
    {

        cout << "Enter beginning balance: ";
            cin >> balance;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision( 2 );

        cout << "Enter total charges: ";
            cin >> iTotal;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision( 2 );

        cout << "Enter total credits: ";
            cin >> cTotal;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision( 2 );

        cout << "Enter credit limit: ";
            cin >> cLimit;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision(2);

        cout << endl;

        NewBal = balance + iTotal - cTotal;

       if ( NewBal >= cLimit ) {

                    cout << "Account: " << setw(9) << aNum << endl;
                    cout << "Credit limit: " << cTotal << endl;
                    cout << "Balance: " << setw(9) << balance << endl;
                    cout << "Credit limit exceeded." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Programmers. Despite the name, we aren't the site for this question. We'll see about a migrate to stack overflow. Have a pleasant day :)

Comment: That's ok - we'll flag the question to be migrated automatically to Stack Overflow for you - which is the more appropriate site for this type of question.

Comment: Why are you doing the `setiosflags` and `setprecision` four times?

Comment: Oh cuz I want it to have a decimal point. Like this, 1.00

Answer (score 1):

I'd structure the code like this:

```
while(true)
{
  cout << "Enter account number: ";
  cin >> aNum;
  if(aNum==-1) break;

  // ... Rest of your while loop ...
}
```

Comment: Wow it worked :D! Ty One thing, why did you add (True) next by while?

Comment: @MintIceCream The `while(true)` means "loop forever". The `break` means "stop looping".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code below

```
/* Make a program that will determine if a department store customer has exceeded the
credit limit on a charge account*/
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int aNum,Always;

    double balance,iTotal,cTotal,cLimit,NewBal;

    do 
    {
        cout << "Enter account number: ";
        cin >> aNum;
        if(aNum != -1)
        {
        cout << "Enter beginning balance: ";
            cin >> balance;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision( 2 );

        cout << "Enter total charges: ";
            cin >> iTotal;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision( 2 );

        cout << "Enter total credits: ";
            cin >> cTotal;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision( 2 );

        cout << "Enter credit limit: ";
            cin >> cLimit;
            cout << setiosflags( ios::fixed | ios::showpoint ) << setprecision(2);

        cout << endl;

        NewBal = balance + iTotal - cTotal;

       if ( NewBal >= cLimit ) {

                    cout << "Account: " << setw(9) << aNum << endl;
                    cout << "Credit limit: " << cTotal << endl;
                    cout << "Balance: " << setw(9) << balance << endl;
                    cout << "Credit limit exceeded." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
       }
     }
    }while ( aNum != -1 );
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps...